# Scope issue when chaining Javascript promises serially with reduce

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have a collection of items that I need to delete from a db. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
getSomeItems.get()
    .then(function(result) {
        var actions = [];
        if (result.count) {
            result.data.forEach(function(item) {
                actions.push(function() {
                    console.log("Delete old item", item.id); 
                    return delAnItem(item.id); 
                });
            });
        }
        return actions.reduce(function(last, f) {
            return last.then(f);
        }, Q());
   });
```

Given the following data:

```
{
    count: 3,
    data: [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 }
    ]
}
```

I want the output:

```
Delete old item 1
Delete old item 2
Delete old item 3
```

I get the output (as you may have guessed):

```
Delete old item 3
Delete old item 3
Delete old item 3
```

I know this this is because my item is in a higher scope (the forEach), but what I don't know is how to fix it and get the variable into that local scope.

Comment: `I get the output (as you may have guessed):` - I didn't guess that, nor did I expect it with that code - perhaps your input data isn't what you expect - no matter how I "dummy up" the functions you haven't (and don't need to) post, I get what you want as the output

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I did simplify my code when I put it in here. (It's actually nested in an async series, with a bunch of callbacks in between too.) The problem then is probably in my data coming in, being messed up somewhere up the chain. Or some weird async issue that I'm creating for myself. I was sure I'd isolated it to a scope problem. :'(

Comment: the scope looks fine to me

Comment: please add your solution as an answer and accept it if you found one :)

Comment: You would get scope problems if you had used a `for` loop instead of the `forEach` method. Btw, you should rather use `map`+`reduce` or even only `reduce` alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Copied from the author's post:

After some feedback, this actually runs fine. Scope is good. Here's a full, runnable test:

```
var getSomeItems = function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    deferred.resolve({ 
        count: 3, 
        data: [ 
            {id: 1}, 
            {id: 2}, 
            {id: 3}, 
        ]
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

getSomeItems()
.then(function(result) {
    var actions = [];
    if (result.count) {
        result.data.forEach(function(item) {
            actions.push(
                (function() {
                    console.log("Delete old item", item.id); 
                })(item)
            );
        });
    }
    return actions.reduce(function(last, f) {
        return last.then(f);
    }, Q());
});
```

That means my problem is coming from further upstream. Dammit.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer you have figured out by yourself you can use bind method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

It's a fairly common error that could be easily solved and appeared at SO many times. Also simple and clean:

```
result.data.forEach(function(item) {
    actions.push(function() {
         console.log("Delete old item", this.id); 
         return delAnItem(this.id); 
    }.bind(item));
});
```